# Convert an Entity to a FormCollection type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to convert an Entity to a FormCollection type?

The reason is I need to invoke controllers from a console app to quickly import some data I'd like to:

1) Instantiate an entity
2) Convert to FormCollection type
3) Invoke controller method.

I am aware that controllers can directly accept Entity types but at the time of development I didnt have this knowledge and developed the application using the formcollection as the input type.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just send a post request to your controller action with the appropriate post variable names. This can then be referenced in the action

Comment: I've added a reference from the console app to my MVC3 app so I could directly instantiate controllers and invoke methods, as I'd like to quickly import some data. If I understand you correctly  you suggest I send a post request from the console app.I'f I do this I'd have to handle logging in to the application, setting up the httprequest instance, setting the values, handling response which I think is more tedious.... I'd rather directly invoke the method...

Comment: Ok I see. I have not tried to instantiate the form collection outside of a proper web request. I have however overridden various properties of the http request using a mocking framework, but that is typically done in the context of unit testing which may not be appropriate here